# Image upload to Azure storage from xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-blob-storage, blobstore

How can I upload image blob to azure storage from xamarin.ios?
from the doc, i have studied this the method UploadFromFileAsync() works but it needs image as a string path, and i have image as a UIImage var.
How can I convert image to string path to be fit for this method parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `UIImage` to a `PNG` or `JPG` and that becomes a `NSData` object that you can save to the file system.

In the example below, I am saving the `UIImage`-based variable as a JPG to a file in the App's Cache/Temp directory. After that you can use your `UploadFromFileAsync` method:

```
using (var nsData = uiImage.AsJPEG(100)) // or .AsPNG...
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyImage.jpg");
    nsData.Save(filePath, true);
}
```

Note: The file can/should be deleted after the upload completes, but since it is in the cache directory, the OS can reclaim it if space it needed, or the device is rebooted.